# Does fstack-protector linked with execstack protect against a buffer overflow attack?

Tags: buffer-overflow

Im having trouble understanding what these two exactly do. And what the prevent when turned on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fstack-protector is a protection that will put some random content called stack canary before return address of your function call

Before return, it will check the random content is the same as before then return, otherwise it exited.

Because buffer overflow attack is try to overwritten the return address of function, it must overwrite stack canary.

But stack canary is generated randomly, so it could used to prevent overwrite the return address.

Buffer overflow attack also comes with shellcode.

Overwrite the return address and point to your shellcode and then generate the shell.

Execstack is a protection to prevent this happen.

The input buffer is on the stack and your shellcode is, too.

But execstack make memory area of stack non-executable.

When program return to shellcode, it will find out this memory area is non-executable.

It will cause segmentation fault.